# ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'init_8' type=NoOp> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor.

Tags: keras

I'm working with the Keras library and I'm simply trying to initialize the VGG16 model, and I'm getting an error about all the inputs not being an element of this graph. I am using a Tensorflow backend.

**input:**

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

model = VGG16()
```

**output:**

> runfile('C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Testing/vgg_tester.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Testing') Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Testing/vgg_tester.py', wdir='C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Testing')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Testing/vgg_tester.py", line 11,
>   in 
>       model = VGG16()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\vgg16.py",
>   line 163, in VGG16
>       model.load_weights(weights_path)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py",
>   line 2708, in load_weights
>       self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py",
>   line 2794, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
>       K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 1860, in batch_set_value
>       get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 121, in get_session
>       _initialize_variables()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 273, in _initialize_variables
>       sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 778, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 969, in _run
>       fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 408, in **init**
>       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 238, in for_fetch
>       return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 274, in **init**
>       'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e)))
>
> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot
>   be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init_11" op: "NoOp"
>   input: "^block1_conv1_W_8/Assign" input: "^block1_conv1_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block1_conv2_W_8/Assign" input: "^block1_conv2_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block2_conv1_W_8/Assign" input: "^block2_conv1_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block2_conv2_W_8/Assign" input: "^block2_conv2_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block3_conv1_W_8/Assign" input: "^block3_conv1_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block3_conv2_W_8/Assign" input: "^block3_conv2_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block3_conv3_W_8/Assign" input: "^block3_conv3_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block4_conv1_W_8/Assign" input: "^block4_conv1_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block4_conv2_W_8/Assign" input: "^block4_conv2_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block4_conv3_W_8/Assign" input: "^block4_conv3_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block5_conv1_W_8/Assign" input: "^block5_conv1_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block5_conv2_W_8/Assign" input: "^block5_conv2_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^block5_conv3_W_8/Assign" input: "^block5_conv3_b_8/Assign"
>   input: "^fc1_W_4/Assign" input: "^fc1_b_4/Assign" input:
>   "^fc2_W_4/Assign" input: "^fc2_b_4/Assign" input:
>   "^predictions_W_4/Assign" input: "^predictions_b_4/Assign" input:
>   "^cond_153/switch_f"  is not an element of this graph.)

Answer (score 0):

I pulled open the VGG16 code and the docs mentioned having

> "image_data_format": "channels_last"

included in the keras config JSON file. Adding that seemed to fix the problem.

Not sure the difference between that and:

> "image_dim_ordering": "tf"

but having both seemed to work.

Comment: Data format can vary from NHWC and NCHW, read: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide