# Unable to load model keras [Django]

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

I'm developing a web app where the user uploads an image and then I predict it using my model which is saved in my hard disk. I'm not sure what is causing the error. Is it image-related?

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'init' type=NoOp> cannot be 
interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^dense_1/kernel/Assign"
input: "^dense_1/bias/Assign"
input: "^dense_2/kernel/Assign"
input: "^dense_2/bias/Assign"
input: "^dense_3/kernel/Assign"
input: "^dense_3/bias/Assign"
  is not an element of this graph.)
```

My Keras config file is:

```
{
      "epsilon": 1e-07,
      "floatx": "float32",
      "image_data_format": "channels_last",
      "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

My python code to load model is:

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

Comment: might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497869/valueerror-fetch-argument-tf-operation-init-8-type-noop-cannot-be-interpret (added "image_dim_ordering": "tf" to keras config)

Comment: Tried that. Did not work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Then it's really going to be specific to your image or model in this case. If it works on one image, but not another, you have a bad image. If it doesn't work on any images, you have a bad model.